# Is an infant child long or tall?

Tags: word-usage

I was describing my 8 week old child to someone recently and struggled to pick the correct word for her height/length. "Tall" doesn't feel quite right for something whose natural orientation is horizontal.

Tall doesn't seem right because they can't stand or sit yet.

Comment: If her name is Sally, she could be long and tall according to the Beatles.

Comment: I think Sally would be a 'someone' not a 'something'.

Comment: Does a 7-foot man stop being tall when he goes to bed?

Comment: Judging by the results of a search for *baby long,* using "long" is not uncommon at all.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The OP's point about *natural orientation* is relevant here, though.

Comment: @Lawrence Yes; [these WHO charts](http://www.who.int/childgrowth/standards/chts_girls_p.pdf?ua=1) swap from l vs age plots to ht vs age plots at age 2. This is broad-brush, as some toddlers start walking well before 2. [ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/height) makes the sensible call: << height: the measurement of someone or something from head to foot or from base to top >> // << tall: of great or more than average height >>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least in the United States, it is common for medical people
to speak of the 
**length** of an infant rather than the height.
For example, [see the data for length vs. age](https://www.cdc.gov/growthcharts/html_charts/lenageinf.htm)
from the United States Center for Disease Control.

Since parents are often shown growth charts from similar sources
(referring to the infant's length rather than height),
this should be a familiar use of words for most parents.
It is possible that you might have to explain yourself when speaking with childless people, however.

Comment: I think it's the same here (Ireland) now that you mention it.